# Grid made from material

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to create a grid using transparent shader in material.
Unfortunately the result shows the holes in the surface, but walls inside the cube are not really solid. Is there a better way to make it look more solid?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Lutz, your material is - at least for me - pretty complicated and i don't understand why you used transparent shader at all? Can you explain a bit more why you used it?

Comment: i am sorry, but i think my shading knowledge is not enough to solve this... :(

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for the cryptics :-) I tidied up the file to make it more obvious, what I try to do. Please excuse writing errors due to I am german native speaker. If you find one you can keep it.

Comment: My customers often use stairways in there plants that are made from grates. Unfortunately these grates leed to a massive increase of vertices in my modells and ssometimes it takes me hours to correct the meshes on changes.

I tried modifiers but that's just another way to generate (virtual) vertices.
With my material there is no need for extending any parameters to fill the mesh with the desired effect.

But perhaps I am wrong with my way resolving the problem using materials. Perhaps the geometry nodes are a better way. But on this topic I am yet very unexperienced.

Comment: no, you ARE NOT unexperienced (at least not with shaders) if you can make THAT!! Did you ever just tryout array modifiers? for me it looks like this could work in your case and array modifiers don't increase your vertices...

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=oqEvD3RZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/oqEvD3RZ/)

Comment: Thanks for the flowers, but beginners like me are hunters and collectors. My EXPERIENCE has a certain source of knowledge I really love. Look at youtube for cgmatter aka default cube. He makes really great tutorials about materials and vfx editing. Kind of complicated but with unbeliveable cool results.

I am sorry to make you sad saying that array modifiers "virtually" increase your number of vertices the same way the subdivision surface modifier does. Look to the bottom of your Blender window to the stats and watch the nomber of verts increasing while you extend your array.

Comment: Additionaly I have no control of the bar width or the hole width to exactly match my given geometry. With my input values I can tweak the dimensions of the grid. I am just unlucky with this fluffy look of the "solid" volume.